# Fetch API get raw value from Response

Tags: react-native, promise, fetch-api

I use React-Native request some data, here is my code:

```
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/docs/MoviesExample.json')
      .then((response)=>{
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((responseJSON)=>{
        callback(responseJSON)
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error);
      })
      .done()
```

I see the `response` is a `Response` object, and the `json` function code is `return this.text().then(JSON.parse)`, I'm confused that what is the parameter of the`JSON.parse`? Is that the `response` raw value? How can I get it?

Comment: Evidently `this.text()` returns a promise that is fulfilled with the text content of the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer。I've got the raw text use code `.then(response=>response.text()).then(text=>console.log(text))`, but can I get the text in chrome console?

Comment: what do you mean by `can I get the text in chrome console?`

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not good at english. I mean output the text in Console of Chrome Browser, the debugger. I'm trying to output `response.text()`，it's a `Promise` object, can I get the text(not `Promise` object) directly in console?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how you'd do what you want.  In my case I wanted to manually parse the JSON because a certain character (\u001e) is improperly parsed by the in-built JSON parser.

Change from:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    .then((data) => {
        data....
```

to:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text()) 
    .then((dataStr) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
        data...
```