# React with Node getting json data from res.status.json()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am running a react app with nodejs acting as an api to connect to my database.

For my log in I am sending data to the server, and it is returning a pass or fail.

However I am not sure how to extract this json object.

I have looked at the request and response, and as I have manipulated the json object the response content-length has been changing so I believe it must be there somewhere.

SERVER CODE:

```
app.post('/api/checkLogin', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    try{
        let state = await DB.checkPassword(username, password);
        console.log(state);
        if(!state){
            res.status(401).json({
                error: 'Incorrect username or password',
                yay: 'idk work?'
            });
        }
        else if(state){
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'we in boys'
            });
        } else {
            res.status(6969).json({
                err: 'idk mane'
            });
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/api/checkLogin', {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({username: this.state.username, password: md5(this.state.password)}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if(res.status ===200) {
                this.props.loggedIn();
            } else if(res.status ===401){
                console.log(res.status);
                alert('wrong username or password');       
            }else{
                const error = new Error(res.error);
                throw error;
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });
    }
```

What I was sort of expecting as a way to extract the data would be.

On the server:

```
res.status(200).json({ message : 'mssg'});
```

On the client:

```
console.log(res.status.message) // 'mssg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jin and this post I found for the help [Fetch API get raw value from Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339090/fetch-api-get-raw-value-from-response)

I have found that both
`res.status(xxx).json({ msg: 'mssg'})` and `res.status(xxx).send({msg: 'mssg'})` work.

The json, or sent message can then be interpreted on the client side with a nested promise. This is done with...

```
 fetch('xxx',headers n stuff).then(res => {
       res.json().then((data) => {console.log(data.message)});
       //'mssg'
       res.text().then((data) => { let data1 = JSON.parse(data); console.log(data1.message);});
       //'mssg'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, using `res.status(200).send({message: 'mssg'})` is better.

And you can get data after calling api by using `res.data`.

Then you can get result as below:

```
{
    message: 'mssg'
}
```

Comment: doesn't express send a 200 status code on `res.send()` by default?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help.

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
     const userData = {
         username: this.state.username, // I like to store in object before passing in
         password: md5(this.state.password)
        }        
        fetch('/api/checkLogin', {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(userData), //stringify object
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()) // convert response
        .then(responseData => {
          let status = responseData.whatObjectWasPassedFromBackEnd;
           status === 200 ? do something on pass:  do something on fail
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });
    }
```